# Getting backtrace in gdb pretty printer errors

Tags: python, gdb

I am using custom prertty printers written in Python in gdb. If the pretty printer throws an exception, I get an error message. However, there is no backtrace, so it can be difficult to figure out the origin of the error. Is there any way to print a backtrace in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, put this into your `~/.gdbinit`:

```
set python print-stack full
```

Then gdb will print the full Python stack trace for errors like this.